# Is there a method to time how long it takes to receive a DHCP lease?

Tags: dhcp

I'm with an enterprise networking team and we're trying to collect some metrics on our dhcp and how long it takes devices at various locations around our campus to receive an IP address after renewing a dhcp lease. Is there a method on OSX/Linux to time this?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Okay so after some more searching I have decided to just use Wireshark and see the time difference between DHCP request and ACK packets.